How to Click on a Shape, and Display the Contents of Another Cell in the Workbook?
all. I am using Microsoft Office Professional 2013.
I would like to be able to click on a shape (a "group" of shapes), and display the contents of a cell that is on another sheet.
For example:
I have a group (image + text box) that displays a vegetable (in this example, a Cucumber).
Cucumber
I would like to click on the Cucumber image, and see the contents of a cell in the workbook that contains possible companion plants for that vegetable (in this case, a cucumber).
Companion Plants
Is that possible?
Thanks!

It is possible indeed. You will likely need a dedicated label/range to host the data and a macro that will actually report the data in said label/range when you click on the group of shapes. Altough the code could be reduced down to a single line of code, i think you'll still need it if you want to "click and get". That if we assume there are no items like option buttons that can be linked to cells; in such case, you wouldn't strictly need a macro. Anyway can't say much without more detailed informations. What have you tried so far? What's your overall objective?
